# Holding down arrow key no longer quickly moves cursor to the right or left

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

I use an iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6. I use the command line a lot and recently its developed a problem. I would use the left or right arrow key to move the terminal cursor along a previous command or line. If I made a mistake in a long line I was typing on the command line I would hold down the left arrow key and the cursor would quickly move along the line until I got to where the mistake was. That has stopped happening. Holding down the arrow key takes a second or more to move a single space. Continuing to hold it down is just too slow. It's much faster now to just repeatedly tap the arrow string. This is very frustrating and time-consuming. Does anyone know what happened? The arrow keys used to work fine. I've tried restarting but that hasn't helped. This also happens in text windows and other applications.

Comment: it still works on my 10.13.6

Comment: Yes, this happened well after I updated my system.  Thanks. I just included my system version for completeness.

Comment: does it work in other places like Notes ?

Comment: No, it's very slow everywhere I have tried it.

Comment: 2 more questions, do you use the build in keyboard, is your system preferences settings "standard" ?

Comment: That fixed it. It was the setting in the System Preferences/Keyboard. There are sliders for how fast to repeat a key. If you want to write that up as an answer i'll except it. your question about System Prefs caused me to check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your settings in System Preference[image] Keyboard are off

Move the Delay Until repeat Slider to the right to as fast you like it